# Grails hasMany bulk create

Tags: grails

I am trying to implement a "bulk" insert for hasMany.  And got it 90% there, but hit a hiccup with my polyclass design.  I have a model like

```
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [references: Reference]
}

class Reference { 
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
    String name
}

class ConcreteReference extends Reference{
    String childName
}
```

I was able to get the create `working`(defined by creating records) by having markup like

```
<form action='reference/1/edit>
 <input name='references[0].name' value='name1' />
 <input name='references[0].childName' value='childName1' />

 <input name='references[1].name' value='name2' />
 <input name='references[1].childName' value='childName2' />
</form>
```

But the issue is it always creates the concrete type(class='domain.Reference'), so "child name is always null.

I used:

```
def edit(def id){
    def parent = Parent.get(id)
    //i actually clear all the old references first (didn't show that code)
    parent.properties = params
    parent.save(flush:true)
}
```

How can I either specify the "concrete type"( I tried a hidden value of class it didn't work) or is there an easy way to loop through params.reference[idx] create it and then add it to Parent?

hopefully that is clear, let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: `ConcreteReference extends Reference` is what you meant?

Comment: Is `Reference` an abstract class? If yes, do you have `Reference` inside `grails-app/domain` or `src/groovy`?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is but I tested your code it works great for me. Only difference is that I am not submitting from a `form` but going with a REST call. I you want I can submit my setup as an answer for you to review (did not want to clutter your question)

Comment: [This is how](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5775252/) it works successfully for me. Content of Domain objects are copied from your question. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am in different machine right now, but here is what I post `references[0].name=John` `references[0].childName=JohnJr` `references[1].name=Bill` `references[1].childName=Mike`. It is mentioned in the url as well from the pastebin.

Comment: Nobody did. I think you added it by mistake. Have a look at the history of edits. I edited one piece to refer `Reference` as a concrete class instead of `abstract` after looking at your comments.

Comment: @dmahapatro your example is incorrect, my domain is using Reference as the hasMany.  That is why your example works.

Comment: Yes figured that out. I am able to replicate your issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My manual way of parsing params(not I hard code ConcreteReferences, but i was able to group the params):

```
def refRegex = /^([a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\])/
for (ref in params.groupBy { it -> it.key.find(refRegex)}.findAll{it.key}){
    //this will be like references[0]: [references[0].name : 'test', etc]
    //for each one create a FreeFormReference
    def _ref = new ConcreteReference(ref.value.collectEntries{it -> [it.key.replace(ref.key + '.', ''),  it.value]})
    log.info('created reference ${_ref}')
    parent.addToReferences(_ref)
}
```